# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' for the string +91

Tags: regex

I am using below regular expression string to replace the supplied string with ****

```
String output=output.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)(?i)"+requesterView.getFirstname()+"(?!\\w)","****");
```

Above the supplied string `+91`

If it contains `+` then getting below exception

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 12
(?<!\w)(?i)(+91)(?!\w)
            ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
```

How to resolve above exception ?

Comment: never add unescaped string from user to regex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape regex meta-characters in your input String, which you can do with the `Pattern.quote(String str)` static method :

```
String output=output.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)(?i)"+Pattern.quote(requesterView.getFirstname())+"(?!\\w)","****");
```

Currently Java tries to parse the tokens of the input string `(+91)` as regex tokens and fails to make sense of the `+` meta-character in the context it's found in. Additionnally the parenthesis would have been understood as a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Like Aaron mentioned you need to quote the regular expression.

This can be achieved either with `Pattern.quote` or using `\Q` together with `\E`. Here is an example:

```
public static String transformRegex(String input, String testStr) {
    return input.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)(?i)\\Q" + testStr + "\\E(?!\\w)", "****");
}
```

Here is a test of the method above:

```
String output = transformRegex("+91 123123123", "+91");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
**** 123123123
```